# What IC is this? SMD marked AARY

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet, surface-mount, code

What is this IC?

[image]

Where can I find a datsheet for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found what looks to be [the same IC on AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832848212924.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US).

According to that listing, it seems to be the Analog Devices [MAX8882](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX8882-MAX8883.pdf) dual LDO.

Comment: Just reading through that datasheet, the top marking "AARY" corresponds to part number MAX8882EUTA5.